# VS CODE - How to enable CMD in integrated terminal? (Zorin 17)

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, cmd, gnome-terminal

[Image displaying the available shells to be used in the integrated terminal of VS Code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99awP.png)

A picture is worth a thousand words...

I recently migrated from Windows and I'm using Zorin 17.

Once I installed VS Code, I noticed that I only have two options to use in the integrated terminal.

Since I can do everything in Tilix (especially working with Node.js and Git) but not in the integrated terminal's bash, I thought about adding cmd to the integrated terminal's list.

[Image showing an attempt to use the command npm -v and error output in bash.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/749MU.png)

As shown in the image above, perhaps due to my lack of familiarity with bash, I'm not making any progress in my web dev studies.

I'm here because I couldn't find a solution even after extensive searching on the internet.

Do you know how to activate cmd as one of the options in the integrated terminal of VS Code? Do you know how to use bash to work with Node.js?

Anyway, either of the two solutions would be very helpful, but I prefer working with cmd.

(Just to reinforce, I'm saying this because everything works when I use gnome-terminal.real in usr/bin.)

I searched for some extensions that didn't work, and I also tried to change the terminal.integrated.profile to add a line to cmd, but it seemed too complex and I couldn't find any tutorials on how to do it.

I'm trying to activate cmd in the integrated terminal of VS Code.

Comment: I am confused. Are you on linux or not?

Comment: Hi there!

Zorin 17 is a Linux distro.

Comment: You should not have `cmd.exe` on linux. This is a windows only shell / terminal.

Comment: Your error seems to say that on your linux os you don't have `npm` installed or its binary not in a folder in your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider checking out this reddit post which may prove fruitful for you.

https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/zqs95y/getting_node_to_work_in_vscode_integrated_terminal/

The poster is having a similar issue using Pop_OS which is another popular linux os.

One of the responses suggests deleting their current version of VS Code and downloading the DEB package. Downloading an IDE using package managers such as Snap or Flatpak will prevent your IDE from accessing system binaries.

You can find the .deb file here.

https://code.visualstudio.com/

Hopefully this helps